# Telerik grid, add Id parameter into column commands possible?

Tags: c#, telerik, nopcommerce

C# asp.net 4.5 , MS visual studio 2012, nopcommerce CMS and Telerik.

I have the following code sections:

The Razor **View**..

```
<div>
        @(Html.Telerik().Grid<Hroc.Plugin.Misc.ImageGallery.Models.PictureModel.myPictureModel>()
                .Name("productpictures-grid")
                .DataKeys(x =>
                {
                    x.Add(y => y.Id).RouteKey("Id");
                })
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(x => x.PictureUrl)
                        .ClientTemplate("<a href='<#= PictureUrl #>' target='_blank'><img alt='<#= PictureId #>' src='<#= PictureUrl #>' width='150' /><a/>")
                        .ReadOnly();
                    columns.Bound(x => x.DisplayOrder);
                    columns.Bound(x => x.Description);
                    columns.Command(commands =>
                    {
                        commands.Edit().Text(T("Admin.Common.Edit").Text); // can i pass the id here? as well as delete and update?
                        commands.Delete().Text(T("Admin.Common.Delete").Text);
                    });

                })
                .Editable(x =>
                {
                    x.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine);
                })
                .DataBinding(dataBinding =>
                {
                    dataBinding.Ajax().Select("PictureList", "ImageGallery")
                        .Update("GalleryPictureUpdate", "ImageGallery")
                        .Delete("GalleryPictureDelete", "ImageGallery");
                })
                .EnableCustomBinding(true))
</div>
```

The **controller** section for update delete...

```
[GridAction(EnableCustomBinding = true)]
    public ActionResult GalleryPictureUpdate(PictureModel.myPictureModel model, GridCommand command)
    {
        var galleryPicture = _galleryItemService.GetGalleryPictureById(model.Id);//get selected id?
        if (galleryPicture == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("No product picture found with the specified id");

        galleryPicture.OrderNumber = model.DisplayOrder;
        _galleryItemService.UpdateGallerytPicture(galleryPicture);

        return PictureList(command);
    }

    [GridAction(EnableCustomBinding = true)]
    public ActionResult GalleryPictureDelete(PictureModel.myPictureModel model, GridCommand command)
    {
        var galleryPicture = _galleryItemService.GetGalleryPictureById(model.Id);
        if (galleryPicture == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("No product picture found with the specified id");

        var pictureId = galleryPicture.PictureID;

        _galleryItemService.DeleteProductPicture(galleryPicture);
        var picture = _pictureService.GetPictureById(pictureId);
        _pictureService.DeletePicture(picture);

        return PictureList(command);
    }
```

My **service** class section...

```
 public virtual GalleryItem GetGalleryPictureById(int galleryPictureId)
    {
        if (galleryPictureId == 0)
            return null;

        return _ImageItemRepository.GetById(galleryPictureId);
    }

    public virtual void UpdateGallerytPicture(GalleryItem galleryPicture)
    {
        if (galleryPicture == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("galleryPicture");

        _ImageItemRepository.Update(galleryPicture);

        //event notification
        _eventPublisher.EntityUpdated(galleryPicture);
    }

    public virtual void DeleteProductPicture(GalleryItem galleryPicture)
    {
        if (galleryPicture == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("productPicture");

        _ImageItemRepository.Delete(galleryPicture);

        //event notification
        _eventPublisher.EntityDeleted(galleryPicture);
    }
```

From the code provided, it all resides in my **new plugin**(class library) within nopcommerce.

Basically, when you configure the plugin section, the View displayed shows a list of images, you can then upload a new image to the list which is then displayed.  This section works fine.

The Edit command allows the Telerik command options to come into play, so you can change the display order and description.  However when you want to update, or delete its throws the exception "cannot find ID".

Is there something I'm missing here? I believe its because im not actually getting the specific ID and passing it to my controller method (where the error occurs).

any help would be great!

UPDATE: 02/12/2013 as requested heres the code to get the list of images.

the controller

```
[HttpPost, GridAction(EnableCustomBinding = true)]
    public ActionResult PictureList(GridCommand command)
    {
        if (!_permissionService.Authorize(StandardPermissionProvider.ManagePlugins))
            return Content("Access denied");

        var nop_Image = _galleryItemService.Fetch(); //my image

        var Nop_ImagesModel = nop_Image
            .Select(x =>
            {
                var nop_gModel = new PictureModel.myPictureModel()
                {
                    PictureId = x.Id,
                    PictureUrl = _pictureService.GetPictureUrl(x.PictureID),
                    DisplayOrder = x.OrderNumber,
                    Description = x.Description
                };

                return nop_gModel;
            })
            .ToList();

        var model = new GridModel<PictureModel.myPictureModel>
        {
            Data = Nop_ImagesModel, 
        };

        return new JsonResult
        {
            Data = model
        };
    }
```

Update: 02/12/2013 as requested

```
[GridAction(EnableCustomBinding = true)]
    public ActionResult GalleryPictureDelete(PictureModel.myPictureModel model, GridCommand command)
    {
        var galleryPicture = _galleryItemService.GetGalleryPictureById(model.PictureId);
        if (galleryPicture == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("No product picture found with the specified id");

        var pictureId = galleryPicture.PictureID;

        _galleryItemService.DeleteProductPicture(galleryPicture);
        var picture = _pictureService.GetPictureById(pictureId);
        _pictureService.DeletePicture(picture);

        return PictureList(command);
    }
```

the view

```
<div>
             @(Html.Telerik().Grid<@Hroc.Plugin.Misc.ImageGallery.Models.PictureModel.myPictureModel>()
                .Name("productpictures-grid")
                .DataKeys(x =>
                {
                    x.Add(y => y.Id).RouteKey("Id");
                })
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(x => x.PictureId).Hidden(true); 
                    columns.Bound(x => x.PictureUrl)
                        .ClientTemplate("<a href='<#= PictureUrl #>' target='_blank'>    <img alt='<#= PictureId #>' src='<#= PictureUrl #>' width='150' /><a/>")
                        .ReadOnly();
                    columns.Bound(x => x.DisplayOrder);
                    columns.Bound(x => x.Description);
                    columns.Command(commands =>
                    {
                        commands.Edit().Text(T("Admin.Common.Edit").Text); 
                        commands.Delete().Text(T("Admin.Common.Delete").Text);
                    });
                })

                .Editable(x =>
                {
                    x.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine);
                })
                .DataBinding(dataBinding =>
                {
                    dataBinding.Ajax().Select("PictureList", "ImageGallery")
                        .Update("GalleryPictureUpdate", "ImageGallery")
                        .Delete("GalleryPictureDelete", "ImageGallery");
                })
                .EnableCustomBinding(true))
</div>
```

Comment: please post code for getting list of images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only thing you need to do is assign Id and not pictureId and keep your first code as it is

```
.DataKeys(x =>
                {
                    x.Add(y => y.Id).RouteKey("Id");
                })



 var nop_gModel = new PictureModel.myPictureModel()
                {
                    Id = x.Id,//Changed as you are getting picture by Id
                    PictureUrl = _pictureService.GetPictureUrl(x.PictureID),
                    DisplayOrder = x.OrderNumber,
                    Description = x.Description
                };



var galleryPicture = _galleryItemService.GetGalleryPictureById(model.Id);
```

Comment: sorry this made no difference

Comment: where exactly it is throwing error, at the time of updating record? does it hit breakpoint. what errors are there in ModelState? Check update

Comment: that did the trick, the update now works, however the same is not said for the delete action. pulls back 0 for the id

Comment: have u done same for delete, not Id its PictureId in your case

Comment: yes, the ID comes back 0, i believe its due to  the id not being pulled back by the list

Comment: i swapped to id and checked, so i put that in the list, it comes back with the correct ID(not pictureid) but my getmethod is trying to find Picture ID in this case.  So would should i still be using pictureid? if so whats the problem, OR, should i use the ID and create a new get method in my service

Comment: And yes you have to pass Id not PictureId as you are using GetById

Comment: so far it works! ill do some testing but i think all is sorted!

Comment: after testing ill award you the bounty, (takes 24 hrs to award)